# coredata filtering by date using NSPredicate returns nothing

Tags: ios, core-data

Hi i am new to this coredata. I have two entities CategoryList and ExpenseList. CategoryList consists of two attributes
1.dates (nsdate)
2.categories (nsstring)
and in to many relation with ExpenseList, relationship name is "expenseList"
ExpenseList consists of 
1.amountSpent (float).
I just wanted to know learn about relationship features in coredata. When i tried to create a nspredicate to filter the data by a specific date, its returning nothing. I just wanted to filter the categories attribute content in the CategoryList entity for a specific date. Here is my code

```
-(void) callingByDate
{


NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];

NSEntityDescription *categoryL = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"CategoryList" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

NSSortDescriptor *dateSort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES];

NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:dateSort, nil];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"dates == %@",date];



NSFetchRequest *dateFetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];



[dateFetch setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

[dateFetch setEntity:categoryL];

[dateFetch setPredicate:predicate];



NSMutableArray *results = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:dateFetch error:nil] mutableCopy];

if([results count] > 0)

    NSLog(@"results found");

else

    NSLog(@"no results found");

}
```

when i execute this code in the nslog area its showing 'no results found'. I could not figure out why . Thanks in advance

here is my code to find the end and start of the day

```
-(NSDate *)beginningOfDay:(NSDate *)date;

 {

 NSDate *dat = [NSDate date];

 NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

 NSDateComponents *components = [cal components:( NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit ) fromDate:dat];

[components setHour:0];

[components setMinute:0];

[components setSecond:0];



return [cal dateFromComponents:components];





 }



-(NSDate *)endOfDay:(NSDate *)date;

{

NSDate *dat = [NSDate date];

NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

NSDateComponents *components = [cal components:( NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit ) fromDate:dat];

[components setHour:23];

[components setMinute:59];

[components setSecond:59];



return [cal dateFromComponents:components];
```

when i nslog, the result showing is
startday -2013-04-30 18:30:00 +0000 
endOfDay -2013-05-01 18:29:59 +0000

Comment: @ user523234  i will give it a try. Could you find any other mistakes rather than this. thanks for the reply

Comment: You never actually declare what date is.

Comment: @sosborn yes i did. i declared that in the viewDidLoad. the 'date' string will give the current device date.

Comment: Is that value what you expect it to be when you fetch?

Comment: And do the objects you are fetching have that EXACT date ?

Comment: @sosborn yes i got everything checked. i figured out the problem, its because the time stamping effect. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`date` is actually a timestamp, so doing `==` with it will only return items which have that exact timestamp.

To get all the entries on a specific date you'll want to get the `NSDate` for the start of the day (`startOfDay`), and the `NSDate` for the end of the day (`endOfDay`) then modify the predicate to get dates between those two values using:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"dates >= %@ AND dates >= %@", startOfDay, endOfDay];
```

To calculate the `startOfDay` and `endOfDay` you can either do it yourself manually or there are some other libraries you can use to calculate it such as https://github.com/erica/NSDate-Extensions.

Comment: thanks a lot and that worked well when i tried to give the date explicitly like 2013-05-03 in the ns predicate. But when i tried to find the start and end of the day using function the problem persists. I have updated with my code to find the start and end of the day. Thanks in anticipation

Comment: i could not find any mistake myself with the function to find the start and end of the day. If you could please help me out. thank you very much

Comment: Little bit correction to Predicate, to get **between dates** change `dates >= %@` to `dates <= %@`

Answer (score 0):

i am using this solution for comparing only date without time in this case my date format is yyyy-MM-dd:

```
NSDateFormatter * formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
NSString * dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date];
NSDate *rdate = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];

NSPredicate *datePre = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"date = %@", rdate];
```

You can use date and time both for changing format of date.